# why does sendRedirect not work?

Tags: java, servlets

I really need help in this situation, you can watch my full html page for fully understanding.

Full html page : http://pastebin.com/zKTmaRxx

I will focus to a part of it to explain my problem :

```
<%
if(request.getParameter("type")!=null) {
   UserDTO user = new UserDTO();
   user.setUsername(request.getParameter("user"));
   user.setPassword(request.getParameter("pass"));
   if (userDAO.loginUser(user)) {
       session = request.getSession(true);
       session.setAttribute("user", user.getUsername());
       session.setAttribute("type", "admin");
        response.sendRedirect("products.jsp");
   }
}
%>
```

I already debug and I see response.sendRedirect("products.jsp"); doesn't reDirect the current page to my products.jsp page though user and pass are all OK validated.

. But when I put that out, it redirects OK without a problem
Thanks for reading this :)

Comment: You need to define "doesn't work". What do you expect to happen? What really happens instead?

Comment: why not request dispathcher instead of send redirect?

Comment: does the `user` and `pass` validated correctly with your `userDAO`?

Comment: What do you mean by "But when I put that out, I work nicely." is it that if you put out of IF statement it starts working?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've fixed my question. 
@Naved: Yes, still don't know why. When I debug, I'm sure i step through it ( I mean it's ran .

Comment: @sethu: I've already tried, it doesn't work neither.

Comment: you need to put a return statement after redirect

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that your `userDAO.login()` function works fine and return **true** for the if statement.

Could you please post the `userDAO.login()` function and print out the result running it in this case?